# How to give the border till the end of the body region?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

We are creating a PDF using xsl-fo.

I tried to use

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="myBorder">
    <xsl:attribute name="border-bottom">0.0254cm solid black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-right">0.0254cm solid black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-left">0.0254cm solid black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-top">0.0254cm solid black</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
<fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="myBorder" height="225mm" width="195.0mm">
```

to generate a border till the region body end but it's not generating the way I want it.

It want it to be like this:
[image: expected output]

but the border is generating only till the content not till region body end, and the output looks like this:

[image]

How can I produce the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the border on the `fo:region-body` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-body) and not on the `fo:block`, etc. that contains the text.

Comment: When i use border property at fo:region-body

it's causing validation exception
"Border and padding for fo:region-body "xsl-region-body" should be '0' (See 6.4.14 in XSL 1.1); non-standard values are allowed if relaxed validation is enabled.  (No context info available)"
Could you please suggest

Comment: Since you're using FOP, run it with the `-r` parameter to enable relaxed validation. See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.6/running.html#standalone-start